# Enviar multiplos valores das minhas CheckBox para uma chamada Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho um botão que quando clico chama a minha função ajax.Quero enviar os valores que foram seleccionados nas minhas checkBox.Mas o que chega ao meu controlador é apenas o primeiro valor da minha CheckBox.Ou seja,

> Domingo

E devia enviar todos os valores seleccionados pelo utilizador, do tipo

> DomingoQuarta-feiraSexta-feira

Possível problema:

```
 var myCheckboxes = new Array();
            $("input:checked").each(function () {
                myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
            });
```

Script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {       
        var itensCatequizandos = $("#SelectedCatequizandos");

        itensCatequizandos.empty();
        $("#procurarCatequizandos").click(function () {
            itensCatequizandos.empty();

            var myCheckboxes = new Array();
            $("input:checked").each(function () {
                myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
            });

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCatequizandosByDiasDisponiveis")', // chamar o metodo em json
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { diasPertendidos: myCheckboxes },
                    success: function (catequizandos) {
                        $.each(catequizandos, function (i, catequizando) {
                            itensCatequizandos.append('<option value="' + catequizando.PessoaID + '">' + catequizando.Nome + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                    }
                });        
        });

    });
```

Html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<input type="button" id="procurarCatequizandos" name="procurarCatequizandos" value="Procurar" class="btn btn-primary" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="Domingo" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Domingo", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="Segunda-Feira" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Segunda-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="Terça-Feira" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Terça-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]"   value="Quarta-Feira" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Quarta-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]"   value="Quinta-Feira" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Quinta-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]"  value="Sexta-Feira" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Sexta-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="Sábado" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Sábado", new { @class = "control-label" })                                           
</div>
```

Comment: tente assim na linha                     data: { diasPertendidos: myCheckboxes[] },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo seu código está correto, basta adicionar um `traditional: true` seu ajax que tudo funcionara.

> O atributo`traditional` muda a forma que os dados são enviados para o
>   servidor, sem ele o ASP.NET não consegue fazer o bind pois os dados
>   irão assim:
>
> `'diasPertendidos[]="Segunda"&diasPertendidos[]="Quarta"&diasPertendidos[]="Quinta'`
>
> Já com ele habilitado os dados irão desta forma:
>
> ```
> diasPertendidos="Segunda"&diasPertendidos="Quarta"&diasPertendidos="Quinta"
> ```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetCatequizandosByDiasDisponiveis")', // chamar o metodo em json
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { diasPertendidos: myCheckboxes },
    traditional: true,
    //succes and error
});
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCatequizandosByDiasDisponiveis(string[] diasPertendidos)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Por lapso estava a receber uma string e não um array 'string[] diasPertendidos'.